# Handling write to disk requests from another program

Tags: c#, security, request, disk

How can I run any program and be able to handle its write to disk requests with my program so that it can't write anything without my permission? Is it possible to do this with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) product to track and control (modify or forbid) file operations performed by all or selected applications. CallbackFilter provides .NET API (as well as C++ and VCL APIs). CallbackFilter is the only product of this kind on the market.